# App to quickly generate correctly resized iOS app icons

Tags: osx, image-processing, images, software-development

In iOS development, there are quite a few different sizes of icons needed to make your app look the best throughout the system. Here's what the average list of icon files looks like in an iOS project:

[image: Average list of icon files]

There are different sizes of images, retina versions of those... it's a mess. Is there a tool (preferably OS X) that accepts a huge (2048x2048px) version of an icon and outputs these individually resized files automatically?

Comment: They ask for different sizes not because they can't do it themselves, but because resizing leaves artifacts. Ideally you should take a vector graphic and export to the different sizes (I believe some vector graphic softwares support batch exports)

Comment: I'm using this one. I'm doing some maintenance/features on the repo too. https://github.com/asegurola/Final-Android-Resizer https://github.com/asegurola/Final-Android-Resizer/tree/master/Executable%20Jar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My personal favorite is [iConvert Icons](http://iconverticons.com). I used their online version before they had a mac app, but I find the app to be more convenient:

[image: iConvert Icons UI]

My favorite parts:

1. Advanced options for sizing
2. Not limited to iOS (`.icns` files, xcode iconsets, Android icons)
3. Accepts any size icons, and I'm pretty sure even PSD's
4. Supports both iOS7/iOS6- sizes:

[image: iConvert Preferences Window]

My least favorite parts:

1. The app itself costs $4.99
2. I'm not a fan of the app's grainy UI, but that's just me

Comment: I kind of like the UI, myself. But yeah, $4.99 might be a deal breaker. That's, like, two cups of coffee! (I don't drink coffee, but it sounds good)

Comment: @Undo I'm not a fan of coffee either, but I realized the app was going to work the best for me because I needed to support both iOS6 and iOS7, and another app I used didn't support the changes. I also like the fact that it has favicon support... not that people used favicons anymore.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see more value in it as it seems to be able to do quite a lot more than iOS icons. Missed that before.

Answer (score 13):

I've been using **[iConify](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iconify/id416289784?mt=12)** for quite a while now. It:

- Is free. Yay!
- Outputs all the correct files
- Takes in arbitrarily huge images
- Supports drag & drop
- Works for generating `@2x` and normal versions of other images too

When you start the app it looks like this:

[image: iConify UI]

You drag in your ginormous file to the big well:

[image: iConfigy Drag and Drop image feature]

All the resized icon files are placed in `~/Pictures/iConify/`. It's a truly awesome tool.

Answer (score 5):

**[Asset Catalog Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/no/app/asset-catalog-creator-free/id866571115?mt=12)** is a simple (and free) icon tool.
It supports iOS and OS X icons.

One of the great things about it is that it supports the latest icon assets (as of iOS 8).
[image: Asset Catalog Creator - Main]

A big con is that you have to pay to extend its use beyond iOS (meaning OS X, Watch OS, etc).

It also catalogs your icons, so you can drag and drop the generated assets folder directly into your project.

Comment: Aleksander, I've coded a similar app (Icon Dog) that also included OS X, Watch OS and CarPlay without IAPs, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

**[Icon Dog](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1052532083)** is perhaps the best free solution out there for automating the process of resizing app icons. It supports iOS and Mac icons, including the sizes for Apple Watch and CarPlay apps.

In addition to resizing the icons, it also prepares an Xcode App Icon Set (AppIcon.appiconset) inside and Asset Catalog (Assets.xcassets) that you can drag and drop straight into Xcode.

*Disclaimer: This is my app.*

[image: Icon Dog UI]

Comment: This works brilliantly!  Literally could not be any easier.

Comment: This one is the best here

Comment: I tried it, and it's Awesome! The only issue is that it doesn't have a few sizes, but I managed to work around that! Thanks a lot for the Incredible app!

Comment: Would like to note that the app's no longer free, appears to now be $0.99 in the US app store.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this open app, and happy with it.
You can give it a try.

http://laptrinhcomvn.github.io/app-icon-generator/

It's supporting newest Mac OS X & Apple iOS (from 7 to 12 by now)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Prepo](https://wearemothership.com/work/prepo/), love it!

Drag and drop artwork for quick @2x to @1x conversion and preview Icon artwork in context. Prepo stores all your artwork into a project window ready for batch export or use QuickDrop for super fast @2x resizing.

Speed up your workflow and boost your productivity. Preview your designs in context in real-time on your local device or even to remote devices.

[image: Prepo Screenshot]