# iOS app icon generator

Tags: ios, icon

I am looking for a Mac desktop app that can quickly create all the image icon assets required for iOS8+ deployment. I have found one called iConify that looks great but only does @2x resolutions (so far). Any tips? Would prefer software based rather than online converters.

Please note I did find this answer: [App to quickly generate correctly resized iOS app icons](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/399/app-to-quickly-generate-correctly-resized-ios-app-icons/401#401) – but it's now out of date as they don't appear to support iOS8 (ie @3x) imagery.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a good iOS app icon set creation app I would look at [Asset Catalog Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/asset-catalog-creator-app/id809625456) on the Mac App Store. There is a free versions (that does iOS icons only), but I would recommend getting the full version for $3.99 (as of Jan. 2016).

The reason I like this app over others is that the full version will create icons for not just iOS, but OS X, Apple Watch Icons, CarPlay, and iOS Launcher Screens. It’s the only app that I’ve found that creates all these formats, and the developer does a good job at keeping it up to date.

It is also dead simple to use.

[image: 2]
[image: 3]]